# How to not lose decimal places when doing "longProperty1.divide(longProperty2)"?

Tags: java, javafx, division, javafx-bindings

I have two [LongProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/LongProperty.html) *(there are no decimal places in a long)* variables (`longProperty1` and `longProperty2`). I need to divide them and I need to keep the division result in a [DoubleProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/DoubleProperty.html)  *(there are decimal places in a double)* variable (`result`) **without losing decimal places**.

```
final DoubleProperty result = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.0);
final LongProperty longProperty1 = new SimpleLongProperty(45);
final LongProperty longProperty2 = new SimpleLongProperty(7);
result.bind(longProperty1.divide(longProperty2));
System.out.println(result.get()); //print: "6.0" instead of "6.428571428571429" (lost decimal places)
```

`longProperty1` and `longProperty2` are of type `LongProperty` because they receive very large numbers, so I can't cast them to `DoubleProperties`.

On the other hand, the `result` will receive a value from `0.0` to `1.0` (for example: `0.0`, `0.2975`, `0.5378`, `0.9853`, `1.0`), because in my real problem `longProperty1 <= longProperty2`(for example: `500/600=0.8333`, `1/2=0.5`, `1897/5975=0.3174`, ...).

How to do this?

Comment: There are no decimal places in a `long`.

Comment: @EJP I want the division to produce a double, which has decimal places. So I'm putting the result in a DoubleProperty.

Comment: @EJP I edited the question, do you understand the question now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods provided `LongProperty` (and by other `NumberExpression`s) such as `divide` are convenience methods. You can create a custom binding that does whatever you want:

```
final DoubleProperty result = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.0);
final LongProperty longProperty1 = new SimpleLongProperty(812323534);
final LongProperty longProperty2 = new SimpleLongProperty(956745323);
result.bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() -> longProperty1.longValue() / (double) longProperty2.longValue(),
    longProperty1, longProperty2));
System.out.println(result.get());
longProperty1.set(612323534);
System.out.println(result.get());
```

[`Bindings`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html) is a utility class for creating bindings. Here I created a custom binding that returns a `double` by casting the division of `long`s to `double`. You will lose precision here.

The output of the above is:

```
0.8490488685670847
0.6400068223798362
```

Comment: This fits in perfectly to what I needed, thanks for answering and editing my question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `BigDecimal` for your calculations.
`LongProperty` is just a wrapper for usual long value, so no decimal points.

You can try doing `longProperty1.divide(longProperty2.doubleValue())` as well, which would call `DoubleBinding divide(final double other)`, but I think this would remove the point of using `LongProperty`.

Comment: `doubleValue()` doc says: [`"Returns the value of this ObservableNumberValue as a double. If the value is not a double, a standard cast is performed."`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/LongExpression.html#doubleValue--); Can the **cast** cause me to lose the original long value stored in my LongProperty?

Comment: @Douglas, `double` can hold extremely large numbers, but you would lose precision quite fast, so it's definitely not recommended for precise calculations. So yes, it will probably cause you to lose the original long value.

Comment: @Douglas what do you actually mean by big numbers? If it's less than 10_000 or 100_000, I don't think that you would have any problems with `double`. But you shouldn't use it for important calculations like currency.

Comment: Okay, I do not need high precision in `result`, but I need `result` to be updated whenever the value of `longProperty1` or `longProperty2` is changed; using `longProperty2.doubleValue()` I bind with a constant value, so that `result` will not be updated when `longProperty2` is changed.